# Mixing rams with different frequencies and sizes

Tags: memory, performance

I have a computer with 2× 1 GB DDR3 1067 MHz RAM modules. Now I bought 2× 2 GB DDR3 1600 MHz modules.

My questions:

- Should I remove the 1 GB modules and use the new ones only (2× 2 GB = 4 GB total)? The new modules are faster and I will keep the dual-channel.
- Should I use all of them (2× 1 GB + 2× 2 GB = 6 GB total)? The thing that worries me is will I lose the dual-channel mode if I connect them like this? Also, won't all the modules run at the lowest frequency (1067 MHz)? Will this decrease my performance a lot?

Which combination of modules will give me the best performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the answer is highly subjective.

In general, more RAM provide better performance then dual channel ram.
In general, speed differences in RAM make little, if any discernable difference to performance.
It is not best practice to mix differing RAM types from a stability point of view.

I guess, if it were me, if it was a workstation, gaming box or something which is not mission critical, I'd go for the 6 gig option.

If it were for critical/server use, I'd go with the 4gig option.

Comment: Isn't 600mhz a huge difference between the speeds? What do you mean with "critical use"?

Comment: By critical use I mean "used as a server which must not crash/blue-screen/segfault".   Theres a comparison of different types/speeds of memory at http://www.anandtech.com/show/6372/memory-performance-16gb-ddr31333-to-ddr32400-on-ivy-bridge-igp-with-gskill/12 - Its important that you look at the various tests and not only the conclusions (the big conclusions graph is likely to be misinterpreted).  Alternatively (mark this as a Dupe and) look at http://superuser.com/questions/204694/ram-speed-how-does-it-impact-performance